# Multiple conditionals in if.....else with character and integer variable in C

Tags: c

This is a program to calculate the total price of dish based on type of dish and size of dish. The item number is the itemCode variable and the size of dish is the dish_size variable. However, the input for size of dish is case-senstitve as the program must accept both 's' and 'S' for size "small"

I've set dish-size to recognize both 's' and 'S'. when I run it for itemCode 1 and 4, it's working but not working for itemCode 2 and 3.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    //Declare variables

    int itemCode, dish_quantity;
    char dish_size;
    float dish_price, total_price;

    //Display menu

    printf("\t\t\t\tMenu\t\t\t\t\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Item Number   Dish\t\t\t Dish Size              \n");
    printf("\t\t\t\tSmall(RM)   Medium(RM)   Large(RM)\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("     1        Ikan Tenggiri       10.00      20.00        30.00\n");
    printf("     2        Ikan Pari            8.00      15.00        25.00\n");
    printf("     3        Ikan Jenahak         9.00      17.00        28.00\n");
    printf("     4        Daging              10.00      20.00        30.00\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

    //ignore the above line code, it's to display the menu for the user to view.
    
    printf("Enter item number               : ");
    scanf("%d", &itemCode);
    printf("Enter dish_size (S/M/L)         : ");
    scanf(" %c", &dish_size);
    printf("Enter dish quantity             : ");
    scanf("%d", &dish_quantity);

    if (itemCode == 1 && dish_size == 's' || dish_size == 'S'){
        dish_price = 10.00;
        }
    else if(itemCode == 1 && dish_size== 'm' || dish_size == 'M'){
        dish_price = 20.00;
        }
    else if(itemCode == 1 && dish_size== 'l' || dish_size == 'L'){
        dish_price = 30.00;
        }

    if (itemCode == 2 && dish_size == 's' || dish_size == 'S'){
        dish_price =  8.00;
        }
    else if(itemCode == 2 && dish_size == 'm' || dish_size == 'M'){
        dish_price = 15.00;
        }
    else if(itemCode == 2 && dish_size == 'L' || dish_size == 'l'){
        dish_price = 25.00;
        }

    if (itemCode == 3 && dish_size == 's' || dish_size == 'S')
        dish_price = 9.00;

    else if(itemCode == 3 && dish_size== 'm' || dish_size == 'M'){
        dish_price = 17.00;
        }
    else if(itemCode == 3 && dish_size== 'L' || dish_size == 'l'){
        dish_price = 28.00;
        }

    if (itemCode == 4 && dish_size == 's' || dish_size == 'S'){
        dish_price = 10.00;
        }
    else if(itemCode == 4 && dish_size== 'm' || dish_size == 'M'){
        dish_price = 20.00;
        }
    else if(itemCode == 4 && dish_size== 'L' || dish_size == 'l'){
        dish_price = 30.00;
        }

    printf("Price per dish size             : RM %.2f\n", dish_price);

    //Calculation

    total_price = dish_price * dish_quantity;

    printf("Total charge                    : RM %.2f\n\n\n", total_price);





}
```

Comment: FYI, I've edited the tags on your question: because the site is so busy, it's important to tag questions with things that will get the attention of the people most able to help you. In this case, that's more likely to be people who know about C, not people who know about if statements as abstract concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing parentheses: `itemCode == 1 && (dish_size == 's' || dish_size == 'S')`.